# How can I access value of string placed in async void outside that void

Tags: c#, asynchronous, void

here is my code. I use async void to download some data from the Internet. I store this data inside string variable called "Strona". I'd like to use value of "Strona" outside async void. Is there any possibility to return it in any way or get accesss to it?

```
private async void starthttp()
{
    string strona = "";

    response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
    var nodes = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("alt", "")
        .Equals("Celny")).ToList();


    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
            strona = strona + node.OuterHtml;
    }

    strona = strona.Replace('"', '\u0027');
    strona = strona.Replace("< ", "<");
}
```

Comment: Can't you change return type from void to string and just return it from the function?

Comment: When i tried to change type from void to string i got this error: "The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Async` methods can have the following return types:

- `Task<TResult>`, for an async method that returns a value.
- `Task`, for an async method that performs an operation but returns no
  value.
- `void`, for an event handler

In your case, using `Task<string>` for a task which returns a string instead of void

```
private async Task<string> starthttp()
{
    string strona = "";
    //your code stuff            
    return strona;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy way of doing it is Declare global variable and assign value to it inside your method, So:

```
string stronaValue = "";
    private async void starthttp()
{
    string strona = "";

    response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
    var nodes = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("alt", "")
        .Equals("Celny")).ToList();


    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
            strona = strona + node.OuterHtml;
    }

    strona = strona.Replace('"', '\u0027');
    strona = strona.Replace("< ", "<");
    stronaValue = strona;
}
```

However I would recommend using the method above with Task.